# How to deploy unmanaged package in developer org which has Person Account enabled?

Tags: sandbox, package, developer, upload

I want to deploy package from sandbox org to developer org. In sandbox org I have enabled person accounts and also enabled person accounts in the developer org. Can anybody tell me the process of uploading the package from the sandbox org to developer org?

Answer (score 0):

Package creation feature is only available in developer edition and not in sandboxes.

Now, as you mentioned, you have the components in sandbox and want to move to developer org, then I would suggest to take an extract of all components in Eclipse Force.com IDE, and then use the deploy feature to move to developer edition.

Please make sure to enable person account in developer edition org (target org) as well(if not already done).